# Exchange Server 2003 Defrag Timing

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

I see from posts here that the Exchange DB defrag will not start with the NT Backup running.  What I want to know is if it will start while the Backup is in the Verify phase?  I want to push back the allowable defrag time so it is not running when people start work around 7:30.  Right now the allowable is 5-8 am, and might not finish until 8:45.  I'm not sure if it is because it is still waiting for the Backup Verify to finish or not.

Thanks,

Len

Answer (score 1):

It should.

Which is to say that's the behavior I experience in our environment, though I haven't dug into it too deeply.  With that disclaimer, I think that once `NTBackup` releases its locks, normal database maintenance operations on the mail database can proceed again, and those locks should be released once `NTBackup` proceeds to the `Verifying` stage.

That said, both products are so old, I'm not sure if they actually will behave as one would expect based on their more modern versions.

And, just because it needs saying, both those products are approaching a decade old, and are superseded by versions with much better functionality and support.  I'd recommend migrating both the server OS and the Exchange system to a more modern version, post-haste.